# How to optimize android code using Threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading, optimization

My `Activity` loads about 3-5 sec (too long). 
How can I optimize my OnCreate method using new `Threads`?
Or here are other methods to optimize my code?

I tried to create new `Threads`, but always had problems with accessing to `Objects`, which were generated in work `Thread`.

Here is my `OnCreate` code:

```
  if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXIT_KEY, false)) {
            finish();
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mSignInProgress = savedInstanceState
                    .getInt(SAVED_PROGRESS, STATE_DEFAULT);
        }

        // Setting Content View
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mClient = buildGoogleApiClient();
        settings = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
        settingsVK = getSharedPreferences(VK_PREFERENCES, MainActivity.MODE_PRIVATE);

// Load Navigation Drawer
        getDrawer(
                settingsVK.getString(VK_INFO_KEY, ""),
                settingsVK.getString(VK_EMAIL_KEY, "")
        );

        if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra(JUST_SIGNED_KEY, false))
            initDialog_share();

        // Get and set system services & Buttons & SharedPreferences & Requests
        inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        vk_sign_out = (CustomView) findViewById(R.id.vk_sign_out);

        if (!settingsVK.getBoolean(VK_SIGNED_KEY, false)) {
            vk_sign_out.setEnabled(false);
        }

// VK sign out button
        vk_sign_out.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                settings
                        .edit()
                        .putBoolean(SIGNED_IN_KEY, false)
                        .putString(PROFILE_PHOTO_LOCATION_KEY, "")
                        .apply();

                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, FirstLaunchActivity.class)
                        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));

                finish();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Android AsyncTasks to perform such tasks with which you can also access UI views in onPostExecute() method.
Multiple started asyncTasks execute sequentially be default, but you can execute multiple independent tasks in truly parallel fashion with executeOnExecutor().
Try reading on WWW about android UI to non-UI thread communication.
Hope this helps to get you stared...

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a [ViewStub](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html) - it acts as a placeholder and is replaced by your actual layout when ViewStub#inflate() is called. This will reduce your activity launch time if your layout is complicated. You can also put any expensive method calls in onResume() rather than onCreate() to speed things up.

```
ViewStub stub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.stub);
View inflated = stub.inflate();
```